# Django FieldError

Tags: python, django

How do I request the current user? I want to do something like

```
if user.id == pk
    # something sinister
```

where `pk` is the string used in the `urls.py` as a regular expression search term. I want the user to only be able to go to the folder that is assigned to him via his own primary key. Currently my half-assed function looks like this:

```
def permit(request, pk):
    u = User.objects.get(user=request.user)
    if user.id == pk:
        pass
    else:
        return render_to_response('forbidden.html')
```

This is the view function that the urls.py redirects to. This, however, returns an error:

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: date_joined, document, email, first_name, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, password, user_permissions, username
```

Comment: `request.user` is already user. You can check if `request.user.is_authenticated()`

Comment: Oh, okay. I changed the code, and now it always redirects me to the forbidden page. My code is now " if request.user.id == pk "

Am I correct in thinking that this pk variable that is passed to the function is the same variable as the regx search term in urls.py?

Comment: you must check for if folder's user and request.user is equal.

Comment: Pardon for the questions, but how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if int(request.user.id) == int(pk):
    pass
```

try to print pk, request.user.id and type(...) of both this values

Comment: It works now, thanks a lot. I wonder what went wrong. Isn't user.id an integer?